# Flutter FCM inconsistent notifications after long gaps in use

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM is driving me crazy. I have developed an app that upon writing to Firestore, triggers a cloud function that sends a data message to a topic that the user can be subscribed to. This data message is received either by a background function if the app is killed or in the background, or a listener in the foreground if the app is open. Both will handle the message and display a notification.

Everything works perfectly, however, if I don't use the app for a few hours, and then launch it and try to send my notification, it never comes through. I can see through my logging framework that the data is written to Firestore, the cloud function is triggered and runs, it returns a success message and no errors, and then somewhere between the cloud function and my app, it gets lost. I assume some FCM background process is holding it.

Now when this happens, I have found that if I go into the messaging console and send a test message, that will come through, and it seems to "reawaken" the connection. After doing that, I can send notifications with no trouble again, until I leave the app idle for a long period again.

So I have 2 questions.

Firstly, does anyone have any experience with FCM showing similar behaviour, and if so have you found a way to fix it.

Secondly, does anyone know a way to get log data from FCM itself. My notification is sent from Cloud function -> FCM -> Device. Somewhere in that FCM area it gets lost, or held back. I don't know why and I can't find a way to get a log that reveals what FCM is doing with my message prior to sending it out.

Here is my cloud function (edited some things out)

```
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()});


exports.functionNameHidden = onDocumentCreated("reports/{reportId}", (event) =>{
  const newReport = event.data.data();
  const message = {
    data: {
      message: newReport.userIdRef,
      hash: "hash hidden"
      id: event.data.id,
    },
    topic: "topic name hidden"
    android: {
      priority: "high",
    },
    apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-push-type": "background",
        "apns-priority": "5",
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };


  admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    console.log(message);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  });
});
```

My background function is handled like so

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  var notification = message.data;
... more logic and local notification handling
}
```

And in the foreground I catch notifications in a listener set up in initState

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      var notification = message.data;
... more stuff
}
```

I'm quite confident my background and foreground handling of the messages is not the issue as once that connection to FCM is rebooted they both work flawlessly.

I also will add that adding the notification payload to my cloud function so that FCM sends the notification instead of a data message handled by my app doesn't work great for my implementation, so I'd prefer to avoid this.

- Edit
  This is consistent across both IOS and android

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm going to assume you're using an android device since you haven't specified.

This isn't explicitly spelled out in the firebase documentation, but data-only messages are not meant to be delivered when the app is in the background. I've found that data messages can sometimes be received when the app is idle a short time after the app was open, but after a longer time you often won't receive it. What you're seeing isn't a bug but rather intended behaviour.

Here's the android documentation:

> onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

On iOS, it *is* possible to receive data messages but in my experience, the deliverability isn't something you can depend on most of the time, especially on a device you've been doing any sort of testing on as iOS throttles background messages very heavily.

Unfortunately, this means that you're probably not going to be able to do exactly what you're trying to do using push notifications through FCM. There are potential alternatives you could use instead though.

### Polling

You can use a JobManager or WorkManager to run periodic tasks polling against your server on Android. There are various plugins that can help with that; I haven't used them myself so you'll need to look into that.

### Alternative Services

Most 3rd-party "push notification" services simply use FCM and APNS under the hood. One option that has its own MQTT implementation on Android is [`pushy.me`](https://pushy.me/), which might have better deliverability for data-only messages. I believe it uses APNS on iOS though so you might still have the deliverability issues there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looking through the documentation and peoples experience it seems like as long as you have the aps content aware tag set to true and android priority set to high, data messages should be quite reliable. I'll look into the polling options and see what results I get back.

Comment: Fair enough, although it would be worth testing that in a production-like environment over an extended period of time. [This part of the FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority#using_high_priority_messages_for_android) spells out why - they de-prioritize messages that don't result in a visible indication for the end-user. That doesn't mean it won't work for you at all, but it might not be reliable long-term.

Comment: I've actually managed to work out my issue now. Just didn't have the time to post up here. In the end it had nothing to do with the data messages. Essentially my app is subscribing to many topics at once, and was doing so though a loop. Turns out each subscription took around 1 second to execute. So it was taking about 1 minute to finish all of them. So if the user closed the app during this time, that would never complete. I've moved all this logic to a seperate isolate through workmanager. Works like a dream now.... Except for on IOS because apple hates background tasks. Future me problem :D